# Loop Joomla Modules

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, module, positions

I have 2 positions and 6 modules for each position. I want to show 1 module of each position in each section.
I have the following code:

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="block-content">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="module-left" style="raw" />
        </div>
        <div class="block-content">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="module-right" style="raw" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above code shows all the modules, with the problem stacking the 6 modules of each position within a single section.

I have the modules (module1, module2 ...) in the position module-left, and (moduleA, moduleB ...) in the module-right position

I want to show the sections in the following way

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="block-content">
            CONTENT module1
        </div>
        <div class="block-content">
            CONTENT moduleA
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="block-content">
            CONTENT module2
        </div>
        <div class="block-content">
            CONTENT moduleB
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well from your description I can't figure out for 100% what you trying to accomplish.

But my thoughts is you need to simplify code in `index.php` (remove "block-cobtent") and move it to `html/modules.php`.

It is the way to add custom wrapper to any model. Also functions from that file are added to module setting, so you can switch to needed layout easily.

---

Looking through the code I realized that it can be accomplished with settings also, but it will need to configure each module, and that's not want you want.

What you want is:
Add code:

```
function modChrome_section($module, &$params, &$attribs)
{
    $bootstrapSize = (int) $params->get('bootstrap_size', 0);
    $moduleClass   = $bootstrapSize != 0 ? ' span' . $bootstrapSize : '';
    $headerTag     = htmlspecialchars($params->get('header_tag', 'h3'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
    $headerClass   = htmlspecialchars($params->get('header_class', 'page-header'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');

    if ($module->content)
    {
        echo '<div class="section ' . htmlspecialchars($params->get('moduleclass_sfx'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . $moduleClass . '">';

            if ($module->showtitle)
            {
                echo '<' . $headerTag . ' class="' . $headerClass . '">' . $module->title . '</' . $headerTag . '>';
            }

            echo $module->content;
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

to the end of `templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/modules.php`.

And change your

`<jdoc:include type="modules" name="module-left" style="raw" />`

to

`<jdoc:include type="modules" name="module-left" style="section" />`

---

And solution that author really needs would be something like

```
  $mods_left = JModuleHelper::getModules('module-left');
  $mods_right = JModuleHelper::getModules('module-right');
  foreach ($mods_left as $i => $module){
    ?>
    <div class="section">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="block-content">
          <?= JModuleHelper::renderModule($mods_left[$i]) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content">
            <?= JModuleHelper::renderModule($mods_right[$i]) ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
    <?php
  }
```

Comment: Summary: For each module that is in the module-left and module-right positions, I want the code to start from `<div class="section">`, so that it loads 2 modules per section (1 module per position). Generating the last piece of code from my initial question. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I added your full solution ) Comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for your support, in fact the function I use is similar, but still keeps stacking the modules from 1 to 1. What I want is to show 2 modules in the same section. I will write my solution here, maybe it is not correct but it worked for me. Thanks for everything.

Comment: Oh, seems like now I understand. But for this you need to use either another html structure or don't use `<jdoc:include >` but `$modules = JModuleHelper::getModules('your-position')` and then you render `JModuleHelper::renderModule($module[$i])`

Comment: I've added solution for you

Comment: Excellent, I like your solution, this solves the Original Idea. In my case there were some changes of the last hour, is that in some cases we needed to load 3 modules per section 1 left and 2 right or vice versa. And my little code kept working. Those who want to get the original idea I recommend using the code of @Alexandr

Answer (score 0):

MY SOLUTION was to create 12 positions (6 left and 6 right) and process the modules with the following code:

```
<?php for ($i=1; $i < 7 ; $i++) :?>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="block-content">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="module-left-<?php echo $i;?>" style="curtain" />
            </div>
            <div class="block-content">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="module-right-<?php echo $i;?>" style="curtain" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The idea is create a curtain effect with 2 modules.